Why are there no practical applications of classical expander codes?
In recent years, there is a surging amount of works on qLDPC codes achieving linear/almost linear distance. A lot of them are based on fancy products of expander codes. However, it seems like this is yet far from practical. My question is, classical expander code is also very good, why is there no practical applications of them? Why are the reasons people use other LDPC codes instead? Why is it only of theoretical interest, e.g. proving PCP?
Do we face the same issues with quantum LDPC codes based on expander codes? (I know for sure, in quantum computing, we also need to consider logical gates. But what about other aspects?)

I suspect expander codes are analytically very useful but (1) have bad prefactors and (2) contain short cycles, which makes them perform worse under the mainstream iterative decoders. Not sure where quantum codes based on expandes will end up in the long run, but a key difference is the need for syndrome extraction circuits in QEC, where expander codes have some favorable properties.

@RohanMehta Could you elaborate on your last point? What do you mean expander codes have nice properties for syndrome extraction?

The quasicyclic LDPC codes used in many telecommunications protocols are not that far from “traditional” classical expander codes
